# A contradiction in contrast hypothesis in 2 variables // p-value=0?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

I am doing a problem of hypothesis contrast and I have left the following results for the variable $X$ and $Y$ both normally distributed variables. For several sections I have obtained the following results

- For $\mu_X = 5$      -- I can not refuse this hypothesis
- For $\mu_Y = 4.6$    -- I can not reject this hypothesis
- For $\mu_X - \mu_Y <0.15$  -- I can not reject this hypothesis.

The difference between $\mu_X - \mu_Y = 0.4$ and in the third tells me that it is less than 0,15 so I do not know if it is due to the normal deviation (that I don't know) of the normal distribution or it is for another reason.

Then also another question: can it be the case to obtain a p-value equal to $0$?